# How to set RecordInterceptor for all the MessageListenerContainers created by spring-kafka

Tags: java, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring-kafka 2.5.4 with spring boot 2.3.2. I have some methods annotated with @StreamListener. I want to add a universal interceptor for all the methods. I have been trying it with @EnableKafka with ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory bean but it is not working.

I also don't want to configure ConsumerFactory by my own but let spring-kafka take care of it. I just want to build upon the existing configuration and add my RecordInterceptor on top of it.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that annotation-based configuration model has been formally deprecated. This means that support `@StreamListener, @EnableBinding` etc, will be removed in the next major release. For the past two years we've been actively promoting and supporting [functional style](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages) Please look through the linked documentation as well as  the blog post on [project main page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#overview) for more.

Comment: It may or may not be a problem. But we are using a custom AOP implemented annotation along with @StreamListener for a circuit breaker implementation. With the functional style, we will not be able to use it, imo. We will have to find a workaround for this first. Any Suggestion?

Comment: functions are just beans, so I don't see why can't you use the same approach, but then again i don't know your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spring-cloud-stream does not use that container factory, it creates its own containers.

With spring-cloud-stream, you need to add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean to modify the container(s).

Comment: Ah! got it. Even I was wondering if it was actually used. Tried the same trick and it works. Thanks!